# Sorting Multidimention TMDB API Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a multi dimentional array from TMDB API and when I'm taking list of movies, I want to sort them by desc order of "release_date". Didn't manage how to do it. Can you please help me?

This is an example:

```
Array
(
    [cast] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [adult] => 
                    [character] => Disappointed Man
                    [credit_id] => 52fe4235c3a36847f800c2f7
                    [id] => 306
                    [original_title] => Beverly Hills Cop III
                    [poster_path] => /tw9gAhqQcBFX0X0XfVbWqUsmzoU.jpg
                    [release_date] => 1994-05-24
                    [title] => Beverly Hills Cop III
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [adult] => 
                    [character] => Himself
                    [credit_id] => 52fe43cac3a36847f806fc33
                    [id] => 4539
                    [original_title] => Hearts of Darkness: A Filmmaker's Apocalypse
                    [poster_path] => /iQLXcATpUxrRdEzxoDqzCgYllnT.jpg
                    [release_date] => 1991-09-06
                    [title] => Hearts of Darkness: A Filmmaker's Apocalypse
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [adult] => 
                    [character] => Himself
                    [credit_id] => 52fe45809251416c75058c67
                    [id] => 13611
                    [original_title] => Heckler
                    [poster_path] => /n3uZEZVlPmgJz3Pnijz94sw69Ao.jpg
                    [release_date] => 2007-01-01
                    [title] => Heckler
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [adult] => 
                    [character] => Himself
                    [credit_id] => 52fe45b59251416c9103bb99
                    [id] => 35795
                    [original_title] => From 'Star Wars' to 'Jedi': The Making of a Saga
                    [poster_path] => /umP3Q7dRTi22MCbGHBmw1Aeo5IZ.jpg
                    [release_date] => 1983-12-03
                    [title] => From 'Star Wars' to 'Jedi': The Making of a Saga
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [adult] => 
                    [character] => Himself (voice)
                    [credit_id] => 52fe4624c3a36847f80ef089
                    [id] => 42979
                    [original_title] => Robot Chicken: Star Wars
                    [poster_path] => /kWKspQ7YiQ82xXM1jVbIbqh5OyV.jpg
                    [release_date] => 2007-07-17
                    [title] => Robot Chicken: Star Wars
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [adult] => 
                    [character] => Himself
                    [credit_id] => 52fe4684c3a36847f810367f
                    [id] => 44345
                    [original_title] => The Cutting Edge: The Magic of Movie Editing
                    [poster_path] => /oUepcj7iBKirdscldMvYre2pCtX.jpg
                    [release_date] => 2004-01-01
                    [title] => The Cutting Edge: The Magic of Movie Editing
                )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = [
    'cast' => [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'release_date' => '1994-05-24'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            'release_date' => '1991-09-06'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 3,
            'release_date' => '2007-01-01'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 4,
            'release_date' => '1983-12-03'
        ],
    ]
];

$rows = $data['cast'];
$releaseDates = array_map('strtotime', array_column($rows, 'release_date'));
array_multisort($releaseDates, SORT_DESC, $rows);
$data['cast'] = $rows;
var_dump($data);
```